# python append content in xml file

Tags: python, xml

in python i'm tring to append some xml in a existing xml file. This is my function:

```
from lxml import etree as ElementTree
import os
import string
import sys

path = "file.xml" 

def addEntries(data):  

    EntitiesExtractionRule = ElementTree.Element("EntitiesExtractionRule", Id=data, Description=data)
    TracksideObject= ElementTree.SubElement(EntitiesExtractionRule,"TracksideObject")
    TracksideObject.text=data

    tree = ElementTree.ElementTree(EntitiesExtractionRule)  
    tree.write(path)


addEntries("one")
addEntries("two")
```

The problem is when the function addEntries call tree.write the xml file is dropped and re-writed from scratch. there is a method to append the result of the addEntries function in a xml file without erase the existing content?

Comment: No, I don't imagine there is; no track is kept of *where* in the tree you changed the XML content, so there is not enough information in the tree to rewrite the file more intelligently. Better batch your changes to the tree and write once instead.

Comment: As far as I know, `lxml` doesn't explicitly document that it doesn't do anything insanely clever here… but you can assume it doesn't do anything cleverer than `ElementTree`, which _does_ document that rewriting the file really means rewriting the file.